# mvc3 how can i include a Count method inside a Tolist

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a tolist method that makes changes inside the database but I would like to **Count** how many times my **Where clause is true**. The Tolist works how can i add a count..

```
   // the count to see how many times getid== x.RegistrationID 
List<Article> getprofile = (from x in db.Articles where getid == x.RegistrationID select x).ToList();
            foreach (var items in getprofile)
            {
                items.articlecount = items.articlecount + 1;
                db.Entry(items).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: seems like getprofile.count would give you this answer. But I suspect if it was that easy, you wouldn't need to post a Q. So please clarify further.

Comment: The getprofile.count does not work on a foreach .. well basically the "articlecount" is an INT field in the database its only purpose is to keep count of how many articles a user has created, when you create a new Article the Articlecount should increase by +1 . I use the .tolist and foreach to update the "articlecount" of all the articles that make GetProfile True.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you store the number of articles in db.Article. why not stored in db.User. If you store in db.Article will be difficult because it must change Arcticle.articlecount in each user Articles. I think **your code above can cause uncertainty calculation.** Add article count each time you add article in AddArticle metode.

```
public void AddArticle(Article article)
    {
        ... your add new article code

        // increase articlecount at db.User
        db.Users.Where(c => c.userid == article.getid).FirstOrDefault().articlecount += 1;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

or do not need to be stored, to get the count just:

```
int articlecount = db.Articles.Where(c => c.getid == RegistrationID ).Count();
```

I think it's safer.